# Swift iOS CollectionView xib properties are nil

Tags: ios, swift

BrowseCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class BrowseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIImageView!

}
```

CustomCollectionViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // collectionView?.register(BrowseCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "browse")
    collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "BrowseCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "browse")

    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "browse", for: indexPath) as! BrowseCell
    cell.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))
    cell.overlayView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))
    let test = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return cell
}
```

[image: BrowseCell.xib]

The cells appear blue, so I know the collectionView is working.
The nibName is correct, reuse identifier works. While debugging it says cell.image is nil. I've tried a lot of different combos, and am unsure how to continue. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is actually with the way that UIImageView doesn't work like that. I tried adding a label and it's visible. Oops.

Comment: Check IBOUtlet is correctly connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is assigning in imageView.image

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "browse", for: indexPath) as! BrowseCell

        /// Here you can try making a change 
        /// You are assigning imageView.image a new ImageView which Is wrong 
        cell.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))

        /// Replace above line as 
        cell.image.image = UIImage.init(named: "6")

        cell.overlayView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))
        let test = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "6"))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the File's Owner of the BrowseCell to the ViewController hosting the `BrowseCell`